# Undefined functions send() and receive() on TwoWire/SPI

Tags: spi, wire-library

I have downloaded a sketch that uses SPI.  The sketch includes the Wire library but at compilation time, I am getting errors that TwoWire doesn't have methods called `send()` and `receive()`?

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by the sketch you downloaded being old.  In prior releases, the methods called `send()` and `receive()` were used to send and receive SPI data.  These were renamed to be `write()` and `read()`.  If you change your code where there are references to `Wire.send()` and change to `Wire.write()` and also change `Wire.receive()` to `Wire.read()`, you should find that your applications compile and run correctly.